# No Sound in Arel Wars 2 (iOS version)

Tags: arel-wars-2

I'm playing the iOS edition of [Arel Wars 2](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/arel-wars-2/id546484195?mt=8).  During the game, there's no sound at all; no music, nor any sound effects.  I've tried toggling the audio options off and back on again in the settings menu with no success.

Anybody know why I have no sound, and how to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed this game to test it out myself.

I found that I did not, in fact, have any sound because *my phone was silenced.*

Check to make sure your phone isn't silenced. If it is, simply unsilence your phone.

<sup>Some volume adjustment may be required. Your mileage may vary.</sup>

Comment: Wow.  I really need to learn to start checking this, [it's happened to me before](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17202/why-cant-i-hear-my-alert-sounds-or-ringer)...